# Joining across several tables - then applying a PIVOT to display the data differently

Tags: c#, sql, join, stored-procedures, pivot

I am trying to figure a way to execute a seemingly complex join scenario, and am unsure as to how to go about it.
Some Background info:

-I have a 'ProjectCategory' table, which contains a foreign key 'ProjectID' and 'CategoryID' to the Project and Category tables respectively. One project could have as many assigned categories to it as there are existing (up to 10)

-I have a 'Budget' table and a 'Sponsor' Table.

-My 'Project' table is related to my 'Budget' Table in that all Projects have an associated BudgetID

-My 'Budget' Table is related to my 'Sponser' table in that all Budgets have an associated SponsorID.

-'Project' table and 'Sponsor' table are not directly related.

An example of the result set that I am trying to get is firstly:

```
SponsorName(Field in sponsor table) - ProjectName - Category
___________________________________   ___________   ________
A                                     ABC           categoryA
A                                     ABC           categoryB
A                                     DEF           categoryX
A                                     DEF           categoryZ
```

I would then like to use a PIVOT to show the data like:

```
SponsorName  - ProjectName -categoryA - categoryB -categoryC - categoryD ...
___________    ___________  _________   _________  _________   _________
A              ABC             X            X
A              DEF                          X                      X
B              EFG             X                                   X
```

Where the Xs mark which categories are associated with each project/sponsor combination. The filling in of the Xs is maybe something I will do in the codebehind or using other stored procedures, but this is the basic idea of what I am trying to do.

I am having trouble even figuring out how to write a query to get back the first set before I even implement a pivot to show it as the second set, so I am a bit intimidated by this task. Any help greatly appreciated, and please let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server, I use a stored procedure for the bulk of Dynamic PIVOTS. (Listed Below)

The source could be a table, #temp or even SQL

```
Exec [prc-Pivot] '#Temp','Category','max(''X'')[]','SponsorName,ProjectName',null
```

Returns

```
SponsorName ProjectName categoryA   categoryB   categoryD   categoryX   categoryZ
A           ABC         X           X           NULL        NULL        NULL
A           DEF         NULL        NULL        NULL        X           X
B           EFG         X           NULL        X           NULL        NULL
```

The Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc-Pivot] (
    @Source varchar(1000),          -- Any Table or Select Statement
    @PvotCol varchar(250),          -- Field name or expression ie. Month(Date)
    @Summaries varchar(250),        -- aggfunction(aggValue)[optionalTitle]
    @GroupBy varchar(250),          -- Optional additional Group By 
    @OtherCols varchar(500) )       -- Optional Group By or aggregates
AS

--Exec [prc-Pivot] 'Select Year=Year(TR_Date),* From [Chinrus-Series].[dbo].[DS_Treasury_Rates]','''Q''+DateName(QQ,TR_Date)','avg(TR_Y10)[-Avg]','Year','count(*)[Records],min(TR_Y10)[Min],max(TR_Y10)[Max],Avg(TR_Y10)[Avg]'


Set NoCount On
Set Ansi_Warnings Off

Declare @Vals varchar(max),@SQL varchar(max);
Set @Vals = ''
Set @OtherCols= IsNull(', ' + @OtherCols,'')
Set @Source = case when @Source Like 'Select%' then @Source else 'Select * From '+@Source end
Create Table #TempPvot  (Pvot varchar(100))
Insert Into #TempPvot
Exec ('Select Distinct Convert(varchar(100),' + @PvotCol + ') as Pvot FROM (' + @Source + ') A')
Select @Vals = @Vals + ', isnull(' + Replace(Replace(@Summaries,'(','(CASE WHEN ' + @PvotCol + '=''' + Pvot +  ''' THEN '),')[', ' END),NULL) As [' + Pvot ) From #TempPvot Order by Pvot
Drop Table #TempPvot
Set @SQL = Replace('Select ' + Isnull(@GroupBy,'') + @OtherCols + @Vals + ' From (' + @Source + ') PvtFinal ' + case when Isnull(@GroupBy,'')<>'' then 'Group By ' + @GroupBy + ' Order by ' + @GroupBy else '' end,'Select , ','Select ')
--Print @SQL
Exec (@SQL)


Set NoCount Off
Set Ansi_Warnings on
```

Comment: Interesting approach - so theoretically if I can get a dataset that looks like the first example I showed, I can pass that entire procedure as the @source parameter of your S.P?

Comment: SQL as a parameter, yes.   The results of a stored procedure, no.

Comment: If that base sql is larger or more complex, I find it easier to save the results in a temp table, just more readable

Comment: I see what you mean. Any suggestion on how to join in order to return that first example? I'm currently doing deeply nested selects and joining them together and its not working properly. The Project table has a BudgetID foreign key to the Budget table, which has a SponsorID foreign key. As you can see I'm trying to show the Project-Sponsor relations with each related category, without showing the BudgetID (ProjectCategory table has ProjectID and CategoryID)

Comment: Select B.SponsorName,P.ProjectName ,P.Category From  ProjectCategory P Join  Budget B on (P.somefield = b.somefield)

Comment: ProjectCategory and Budget have no fields in common to join on though

Project: ProjectID, BudgetID, ProjectName (among other unrelated columns)

Budget: BudgetID, SponsorID, etc
Sponsor: SponsorID, SponsorName
ProjectCategory: ProjectCategoryID, CategoryID, ProjectID

So Project and Sponsor aren't directly related

Comment: If there is not link (direct or indirect) I can't help.   You know your data better than I